# Closed-form term for this expression

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, asymptotics, normal-distribution, approximation

I have a normal Distribution $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$. Is there an easy way to give an asymptotic estimate with small error (I would prefer with relative error $\rightarrow 0$) for $P[X \geq k]$?

We have that $k=O(1)$, $\mu=o(1)$, $ \sigma \sim \mu$.

We would write then:

$$P[X \geq k] = \int_k^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}}dx$$

Can we say something like

$P[X \geq k ] \sim f(\mu, \sigma, k)$?

Or at least 
$P[X \geq k] \leq f(\mu,\sigma,k)$ 
and
$P[X \geq k] \leq g(\mu, \sigma, k)$
for some closed-form functions $f$, $g$?

Thank you very much..

Comment: Are you asking for something like [this](http://mikespivey.wordpress.com/2011/10/21/normaltails/)?

Comment: Thank you for the link. Yes, this is somehow what I am looking for. Except that this one is for the Standard normal Distribution, and I would like to have some bounds for a General normal Distribution, where the bounds depend on the mean and the variance.. So is there an easy way to extend this, or does this not work for General normal distributions?

Comment: Make the substitution $z = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$, $\,dz = \frac{1}{\sigma}\,dx$. Then use those bounds.

Comment: So as I am not very good at calculus, I am not sure, whether this is correct:So you suppose
$$\int_{k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}\frac{1}{\sigma} dx \leq \frac{e^{-\frac{(k-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}}{k \sqrt{2\pi}}$$
I have no idea whether this is correct, as I am very bad at taking integrals.. So if you could tell me, whether I have made a mistake, this would be great!
Wolfram Alpha does not help here:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7Bk%7D%5E%7Boo%7D+%28x-m%29%2Fk+%2F+%5Csqrt%282+pi%29+e%5E%28-%28x-m%29%5E2%2F2%2Fs%5E2%29+dx

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Just see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the $N(0,1)$ distribution we have that:
$$\mathbb{P}[X>k]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{k}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2/2}dx =\frac{e^{-k^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-kx}\cdot e^{-x^2}\,dx<\frac{e^{-k^2/2}}{k\sqrt{2\pi}}.\tag{1}$$
You can easily adapt this argument to the $N(\mu,\sigma)$ distribution.

For an efficient continued fraction approximation of the LHS in $(1)$, have a look at [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MillsRatio.html).

Comment: thank you for your answer. do you know some paper where this is stated? As I Need to give the references and Websites are not allowed. So this would be great!

Comment: and by the way, as this is very useful: does there exist something similar for $Pr[X \leq k]$?
I know that one can take $1- ...$, but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: I asked a new question for this:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/900545/closed-form-term-for-this-gaussian-expression